# Should I make an include-file with APC?

Tags: php, caching, apc

With PHP APC activated, does it make a difference whether I include 10 library-files (classes, functions, etc) or 1 file that then includes those 10 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference of an extra include.
Insignificant. Especially if u will use full paths in your include statements and not relative paths.

Comment: So it will not be cached differently by PHP APC? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: well, yes, there will be one extra file included. But really, if it makes your code better maintained to have that extra file, do it. I find it hard to believe your bottle neck will be in that location. and if it is, then PHP is not the language you need to solve your problem.